# handling a modal in vuejs: v-model or bind each element to value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've just started using Vuejs a couple of weeks ago and am enjoying it.

I'm rendering a list of items and have a modal where I need to edit an item and save it.

I have something like this:

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      inventoryItems: null,
      showInventoryItemModal: false,
      selectedInventoryItem: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    willShowInventoryItemModal: function(item){
      this.showInventoryItemModal = true;
      this.selectedInventoryItem = item;
    },
```

and in my template:

```
<div class='bld'>header:</div><input v-model="selectedInventoryItem.header" type='text' size='80' class='ib span12' />
<button class='btn btn-outline-dark' @click.prevent="saveInventoryItem()">save</button>
```

The problem is that if the user closes out of the modal, the underlying list has their changes which are inaccurate. Another choice (which is what I've been using)
    is to set an intermediate item to the selected item and then render in the template something like this:

```
<div class='bld'>header:</div><input name='inventory_item[header]' :value="inventoryItem.header"  type='text' size='80' class='ib span12' />
<button class='btn btn-outline-dark' @click.prevent="saveInventoryItem()">save</button>
```

and then serialize the form and post to the server. This feels wrong (on a couple of levels) but does work. How can I take the selectedInventoryItem and 
    decouple it from the underlying representation so that it doesn't update the backing list until it has been updated on the server?

#### edit 1

saving code:
full template code:

```
  <form id="inventory_item_form">
    <input type='text' size='80' name="inventory_item[header]" :value="inventoryItem.header" class='ib span12' />
    <button class='btn btn-outline-dark' @click.prevent="saveInventoryItem()">save</button>
  </form>
```

and show item and save function:

```
willShowInventoryItemModal: function(item){
  this.showInventoryItemModal = true;
  this.inventoryItem = item;

},
saveInventoryItem: function(item){
  var method = 'post';
  var inventory_item_id = ''; // edit/add
  if(this.inventoryItem.id){
    method = 'put';
    inventory_item_id = this.inventoryItem.id;
  }
  var data_string = $('#inventory_item_form').serialize();  // jquery????

  axios({
    method: method,
    url:'/arc/api/v1/inventory_items/' + inventory_item_id,
    //data: {inventory_item: this.inventoryItem }  // this doesn't appear to update
    data: data_string
  })
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it currently? That seems fine.

Comment: When you say closes out, do you mean cancels out? Typically you just use a copy of the data to make the changes and then update the real values when the changes are accepted.

Comment: thanks @thanksd   well, if I assign to a different object and bind in the way I have, it doesn't appeart to update the inventoryItem and I'm using jQuery's serialize on the form element. Maybe not a big deal but seems like I should have a data variable of inventoryItem that I bind to the input and when I save with axios, it has access to it. Let me update the question because thats the main part that I feel is ugly.

Comment: thanks @Bert I've updated my code in edit 1. That's a bit what I'm doing. I guess where it is ugly for me is using jQuery's serialize to grab the data I submit. Maybe a workaround to this will sit better. Like I said, it works fine, I just don't want to convert 20 of these modals and then wish I'd did it a different way.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I usually handle situation like this:

1. Initialize everything that involves asynchronous in the `created` method. In this case, for instance, getting the data from an API.
2. Use a placeholder to store the item-to-be-edit when a user edits.
3. Save the edits in the placeholder variable.
4. Save the edited item to the API
5. When success, save the final data back into the original data (i.e. `inventoryItems`) with `Vue.set` ([caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)).

You can see I use `fetch` instead of `ajax`, which I recommend but it's only personal preference, and I already made as little changes as possible to your code to suit the placeholder API I'm using ([JSON Placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)).

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      inventoryItems: null,
      showInventoryItemModal: false,
      selectedInventoryItem: null
    },
    created() {
      this.getPostData()
    },
    mounted() {
        
    },
    methods: {
        getPostData() {
          fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
              this.inventoryItems = result
            })
        },
        willShowInventoryItemModal(item) {
          // clone the variable
          this.selectedInventoryItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))
        
          this.showInventoryItemModal = true
        },
        saveInventoryItem() {
          let data = new FormData();
          data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( this.selectedInventoryItem ) );

          fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/"+this.selectedInventoryItem.id,
          {
              method: "PUT",
              body: data
          })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => { 
            console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) )
                
            const indexOfItem = (this.inventoryItems.map((item)=>item.id)).indexOf(this.selectedInventoryItem.id) 
            Vue.set(this.inventoryItems, indexOfItem, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedInventoryItem)))
            this.selectedInventoryItem = null
            this.showInventoryItemModal = false
           })
        },
        cancelInventoryItem() {
          this.showInventoryItemModal = false
          this.selectedInventoryItem = null
        }
    }
})
```

```css
#inventory_item_form {
    border: 2px black solid;
    padding: 20px;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    
    <form id="inventory_item_form" v-if="showInventoryItemModal">
      <h3>Edit:</h3>
      <div class='bld'>header: {{selectedInventoryItem.id}}</div>
      <input 
          v-model="selectedInventoryItem.title" 
          type='text' 
          size='80' 
          class='ib span12' />
      <button class='btn btn-outline-dark' @click.prevent="saveInventoryItem()">Save</button>
      <button class='btn btn-outline-dark' @click.prevent="cancelInventoryItem()">Cancel</button>
    </form>
    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Button</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="item in inventoryItems">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td><button v-on:click="willShowInventoryItemModal(item)">Edit</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    
    
</div>
```